# Using vimeo api (Python)

Tags: python, api, vimeo

I have a mission to get for example the numbers of views of some video on vimeo using vimeo api.

I opened a user (developer), i send request for some video and i recived an html object.

NEW EDIT : This is my code :

```
import vimeo

client = vimeo.VimeoClient(
Api details…)
response = client.get('https://api.vimeo.com/videos/!video_id')
response
response.headers['content-type']

   <Response [200]>
'application/vnd.vimeo.video+json'
```

But i recived an HTML object, my question is if i can get from the HTML object the number of reviews also, or there is another way to do this ?
UPDATE: in the content type we can see that i got the json object as i needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LAST EDIT: although the play count is documented in the API at https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/response/video (under stats.plays) after testing it myself it looks like it always returns "null" - they may have disabled play counts.

EDIT: sorry I misunderstood your need - I thought you were looking for "reviews" so I assumed comments. If you are looking for the number of VIEWS, that should be in the meta data retrieved from "https://api.vimeo.com/videos/!video_id"

so change your line to:

```
response = client.get('https://api.vimeo.com/videos/700495031')
```

Comment: Hey, first i want to thank you, i changed my request but now i recived 401 response with this content : b'{"error":"Something strange occurred. Please contact the app owners.","link":null,"developer_message":"No user credentials were provided.","error_code":8003}'

Comment: You probably haven't input your token/key/secret correctly - did you register your app with the Vimeo API? Read the intro here (https://developer.vimeo.com/api/guides/start), you'll need to register your app, then you'll have a client_id, and can generate a token and get your client_secret as well

Comment: are you including the {} curly brackets around the token/key/secret? You should not include the brackets

Comment: Yes, you right i had {} there, i removed them and now as you can see in the main question i updated my code now. I recived this object  'application/vnd.vimeo.video+json'. There is any way to get drom this object the numbers of views or numbers of likes ? Thank you so much again !

Comment: Try print(response.json()) and look through the data from there. You should probably review some information about working with APIs - here's a tutorial I just found https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-api-tutorial/

Comment: I think the actual data you want will be accessed as response.json()["stats"]["plays"]

Comment: amazing, i got the number of views under this function : res_j["stats"]. Now i try to get the number of likes, i found this object in the data that i recived from my request: "likes":{"uri":"/videos/700495031/likes","options":["GET"]. i tried to print the number of likes with this command without succsess : res_j["likes"] and i recived this message key error..

Comment: Looking at the response I got when testing and based on your last reply this should work: res_j["metadata"]["connections"]["likes"]["total"]
this is way beyond the scope of the original question - please mark as answered and if you need more information spend some time reading up on JSON, and working with APIs in Python.

Comment: Please mark the question as answered